# The meaning of common terms used in monolingual Latin dictionaries

Tags: classical-latin, dictionary

I'm studying Latin with the book Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata. I'm currently in chapter XLIII. When I have a doubt about some word, I can look at the indeces (which is a separate book) to find in which pages that word was used.

I would like to use actual dictionaries, since they are more practical and contain more words that those found in the two volumes of LLPSI. But I have a doubt regarding the meaning of some expressions commonly found in monolingual Latin dictionaries. The following is a screenshot of the word entry for **praetereo** in *Vademecum in opus Saxonis*.

[image]

In this entry, terms like **proprie**, **translate**, **generatim**, **speciatim** and **impersonaliter** appear. What do those terms indicate about the possible uses of the verb **praetereo** ?

Take, for instance, the adverb **translate**. I know that this comes from the verb **transfero, -ferre, -tuli, -latum** by taking the participle **translatum** and changing it to a adverb. But, in the dictionary itself, I don't know what it's indicating about the explanations found in the entry of **praetereo**. In my intuition, I think it's indicating that the entries that follow are the figurative uses of the verb **praetereo** (e.g: neglego, omitto).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you familiar with the adverbs *proprie, translate, generatim, speciatim, impersonaliter*? A monolingual dictionary is of no help if you don't know anything about the language yet. The connections within the vocabulary only make sense if you already know quite a bit. Can you elaborate on your background and what specifically makes you wonder here? (I'll close the question for now but can reopen if you elaborate.)

Comment: I'll be blunter: you clearly speak English, so **use one of the many, many English–Latin dictionaries available and aimed at learners**. (If you speak another language which also has readily available Latin dictionaries for learners, by all means use that instead.)

Comment: I would like to stick with monolingual dictionaries because not doing so  defeats the purpose of the natural method.

Comment: I fail to see the point, but each to their own. I hope someone is able to give you a satisfactory answer in Latin so your natural method learning is not corrupted.

Comment: In a way, though, doesn't any use of a dictionary defeat the purpose of the natural method?

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17733/latin-to-latin-dictionary. Although, I think both your Latinity and dictionary skills would need to be quite good to use a monolingual Latin dictionary.